# Finding all kinds of extensions referenced in a html file

Tags: find, regular-expression, recursive, html

Here is my problem statement :

There is a folder with many html and text files. I need to recursively go through each one of them and find all kinds of file extensions referenced in these html/text files like .jpg, .tif, .png etc

The problem is I don't have a defined list of the extensions I want to search for.

What would be the best way to achieve this using a shell script ?

Coming up with a Reg-ex which would essentially search for all occurrences of a dot followed by 3 or 4 letters, and filtering out the ones which end with a space or a comma, or a quote etc ??

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Keeping in mind that HTML is not a regular language, you could probably at least narrow it down with:

```
grep -Ro '[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}' *
```